# Definition of Lipschitz continuous function in the general case

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

My textbook describes the **Lipschitz continuous function** as follows:

> A Lipschitz continuous function is a function $f$ whose rate of change is bounded by a **Lipschitz constant** $\mathcal{L}$:
>
> $$\forall \mathbf{x}, \forall \mathbf{y}, |f(\mathbf{x}) - f(\mathbf{y})| \le \mathcal{L} || \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{y} ||_2$$

And the [Wikipedia article for Lipschitz continuity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lipschitz_continuity#Definitions) defines the Lipschitz continuous function as follows:

> Given two metric spaces $(X, d_X)$ and $(Y, d_Y)$, where $d_X$ denotes the metric on the set $X$ and $d_Y$ is the metric on set $Y$, a function $f : X \to Y$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a real constant $K \ge 0$ such that, for all $x_1$ and $x_2$ in $X$,
>
> $$d_Y(f(x_1), f(x_2)) \le K d_X(x_1, x_2).$$
>
> Any such $K$ is referred to as **a Lipschitz constant** for the function $f$. $\dots$
>
> In particular, a real-valued function $f : R \to R$ is called Lipschitz continuous if there exists a positive real constant $K$ such that, for all real $x_1$ and $x_2$,
>
> $${\displaystyle |f(x_{1})-f(x_{2})|\leq K|x_{1}-x_{2}|.}$$
>
> In this case, $Y$ is the set of real numbers $\mathbf{R}$ with the standard metric $d_Y(y_1, y_2) = |y_1 − y_2|$, and $X$ is a subset of $\mathbf{R}$.

So, I just want to confirm: The textbook explanation has just chosen the second metric to be the Euclidean metric, but this does not have to be the case in general, as evidenced by the Wikipedia article? I just want to confirm because the textbook passes this off as a general mathematical statement, which is, in my opinion, misleading.

I would appreciate it if people could please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Yes, you're right. In general, you are Lipschitz between two normed spaces, and this is with regard to the corresponding norms in the "start" and "arrival" spaces. Here, the textbook takes the starting space to be $\mathbb{R}^n$ with the Euclidean norm, and the arrival one to be $\mathbb{R}$ (with the usual norm).

Comment: Note that in finite-dimensional spaces, all norms are equivalent, so being $K$-Lipschitz w.r.t. a given norm implies being $K'$-Lipschitz w.r.t. to another norm -- where $K'$ depends on $K$ and the dimension.

Comment: @ClementC. Thanks. But aren't normed vector spaces a subset of metric spaces (and metric spaces a subset of topological spaces), and so the general case would be in terms of the metric space rather than normed spaces, as you stated?

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's from a metric space to another (replace all I've said with "normed space" in my first comment by "metric space"). I was just building up to the second comment, which basically says that if you don't care about the exact Lipschitz constant (note: one often does care), in finite-dimensional spaces you can forget about the specific norm.

Comment: @ClementC. Thank you for the explanation. This is all clear to me now.

Comment: You're welcome!

Comment: I think it's not appropriate to criticize a definition, used in a particular context, for not being the most general that you are aware of, and it's certainly not appropriate to say the more specialized definition is misleading for this reason. For example, we could similarly criticize the Wikipedia definition since one can define Lipschitz maps from one quasi-metric space to another quasi-metric space -- see the lower middle of p. 6 of [this paper](https://hal.science/hal-03187651/document).

Answer (score 2):

You are correct. The book's definition is a definition of Lipschitz continuity over Euclidean spaces. The definition of Lipschitz continuity over the metric spaces is more general. The equation of the book would still satisfy the metric space definition, since all norms are metrics. However, Lipschitz continuity is definable for all metrics, but not all metrics are norms.

Answer (score 0):

For functions between Euclidean spaces when no norm/metric is specified it is assumed that you are using that usual distance function. This is a well established convention. Of course it is  also possible to discuss Lipschitz continuity w.r.t. other metrics on Euclidean spaces.